# How to receive the highest defensive bonus?

Tags: xcom-2

In *XCOM: Enemy Unknown*, [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87338/how-does-cover-work/89259#89259) mentions how defensive bonuses are calculated with regard to the amount of cover, perks and additional buffs.

For *XCOM 2*, I currently have this defensive bonus list:

```
 - Half Cover:                          +20
 - Smoke:                               +20
 - Hunker Down:                         +30  
 - Half Cover w/ Smoke:                 +40
 - Half Cover w/ Hunker Down:           +50
 - Half Cover w/ Smoke and Hunker Down: +70
 - Full Cover w/ Smoke:                 +60
 - Full Cover w/ Hunker Down:           +70
 - Full Cover w/ Smoke and Hunker Down: +90
```

What perks or armors are available to further add to these bonuses? For example, in *XCOM: Enemy Unknown*, the 'Dense Smoke' perk allowed smoke grenades to give an additional +20 defense.

Comment: Hrmmm; don't forget sending a gremlin over to a particular character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at a number of abilities and @Sumurai8's comment, I've compiled that the following list of defense bonuses:

```
 - Half Cover:                          +20
 - Smoke:                               +20
 - Hunker Down:                         +30
 - Gremlin (Aid Protocol):              +20
 - Gremlin Mk II:                       +30  
 - Gremlin Mk III:                      +40
```

Maximum defense can then be gained by using Full Cover, Smoke, Hunker Down and Gremlin MKIII Aid Protocol for a total of 130 defense.

Since defense is a number subtracted from the shot chance, at 130 defense it is not possible to be hit by a shot. Psi attacks and grenades may still hit.

Comment: I'd like to add height advantage which confers a defence bonus of 20 - which I forgot if 20 is with or without the `Damn Good Ground` perk

Comment: `at 130 defense it is not possible to be hit by a shot` A 140% shot (which is shown as 100% in the UI but counts as 140%) would still have a 10% chance to hit. **Hit chance = Unit aim minus target defense**. The dice roll is capped to 100% for obvious mathematical reasons, but the calculations **before** the dice roll are not. However, 100+ Dodge would guarantee a dodge, as the Dodge stat is only calculated **after the roll**.